# Module parse failed or Loader not found

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, es6-module-loader

So I've been trying to add a **CSS** loader into **webpack.config.js**, my code looks like this:

```css
module.exports = {
    entry: './scripts/entry.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { 
                test   : /\.css$/,
                include: /scripts/,
                loader : "style!css"
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

[image]

and here is a picture with all files and path to them, when I call

```
require('style!css!./style.css');
```

it executes nicely, but if I call

```
require('./style.css');
```

the error shows up. Am I defining a wrong path somewhere or did I write the loader wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was in using `gulp.watch()` and compiling with`webpack`

Answer (score 0):

In fact your `webpack.config.js` not used when you run webpack as on screenshot.
If config located not in current directory you must pass `--config` parameter:

`webpack --config=scripts/webpack.config.js`

Comment: I tried running that code, but I get the same error

Comment: It must be `webpack --config=scripts/webpack.config.js`

Comment: yes, it does the same for me, but still leaves the same error

Answer (score 0):

By convention `webpack` loads the config from `webpack.config.js` in root directory. You can move your config file to root with your configuration and it should work